# How to route documents via Content Organizer/Drop Off Library to appropriate document set

Tags: document-set, incoming-email, content-organizer, email-enabled-library

My business partner wants to use document sets. The vast majority of the docs they want to store come to them via Outlook emails as attachments.

They would like to forward the email with attachment (or "save as...") and have it end up in the correct doc set with metadata applied automatically. Is there anyway to do this? I've also wondered if the content organizer could help - i.e. set up the Drop Off Library for incoming email, then have content organizer rules (somehow?) route the documents to the correct doc set. The incoming email attachments will of course have no metadata, so I'm not sure how to accomplish this. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

try using event receiver on the drop off library to get the metadata of the folder to be applied on document.

I don't think there will be any OOB solution of it.